# Multiple php query string and multiple select options

Tags: php, sql, query-string

This is the problem I have. I have a side menu like:

Options A:

A

B

C

Options 1:

1

2

3

Options A and Options 1 are coloumns in a sql table, so If I clicked on A:

```
whatever.php?OptionA=A
```

However I want it to be able to multi select, so if I clicked on A, then clicked on B, it would filter the table so that it shows A and B only.

Also, I should be able to select in Options 1 also, so if I clicked on A then 1 it would be:

```
whatever.php?OptionA=A&Option1=1
```

The main issue is how can I do it so it can show A and B together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use array?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option1[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="option1[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="option1[]" value="3">

<input type="checkbox" name="option_a[]" value="A">
<input type="checkbox" name="option_a[]" value="B">
<input type="checkbox" name="option_a[]" value="C">
```

Then...

```
$box = $_POST['option1'];


foreach ($box as $key => $value)
{
  echo "$key => $value";
}
```

..etc.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some jQuery to achieve this task.

First of, you'll need to bind an event to your `<select>` tags. See the click event with jQuery: [Click event](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Secondly, you will need to execute a PHP script with the post function of jQuery when the click event occurs. Learn about it here: [Post function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Third, now you can execute your PHP script with your post variables received previously.

Your MySql query should look like this (note that you will need to generate your query dynamically):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE (OptionsA = 'A' OR OptionsA = 'B') AND (Options1 = '1' OR Options1 = '2')
```